# NDSolve not working for certain parameters

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I'm trying to solve the following ODE

```
myzero = 0.00001;
q = 0.1;
mu = 1;
f[z_] = 1-z^2;
sol = NDSolve[{ f[z] (z y''[z] + y'[z]) == q^2 z y[z], 
   y[1] == 0, y'[1] == mu}, y, {z, myzero, 1}]
```

Mathematica is able to solve it for `q=0` but for any finite real value it returns the errors `Power::infy`, `Infinity::indet` and consequently `NDSolve::ndnum` (non-numerical value for the derivative). Curious what's the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maple says "Error, (in DEtools/convertsys) unable to convert to an explicit first-order system ".

Comment: Ignoring error messages doesn't seem wise.  (I included a brief synopsis of them.)

Answer (score 3):

The derivatives on the left hand side of your differential equation are multiplied by `f[z]`, which is zero at `z=1`.  This leads to the error messages

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at z == 1.`.
```

because `NDSolve` seems to divide by `f[z]` in setting up to solve the equation numerically.

One possible solution is to stop just short of `z=1`, as you do with `z=0` already.

```
sol = NDSolve[{f[z] (z y''[z] + y'[z]) == q^2 z y[z], y[1 - myzero] == 0,
  y'[1 - myzero] == mu}, y, {z, myzero, 1 - myzero}]
```

seems to work.

Comment: It should be noticed you present a substitute, not a solution for the posed problem (which likely has no solution) @Chris K (which disappears when submitting).

Comment: Thank you Chris! @user64494 I guess you're right, at z=1 there's singularity, nevertheless for me Chris's solution works :)

Comment: @Skylar15: The question arises: how to apply it to the ill posed problem under consideration? BTW, the ParametricNDSolve command (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html ) may be applied here

Comment: @user64494 I suppose I meant "solution" in the colloquial sense of "a means of solving a problem or dealing with a difficult situation", not the mathematical sense ;-)

Comment: @Chris K: Isn't the use of ParametricNDSolve a better way to this end?

Comment: @user64494 I don't know.  I haven't made much use of `ParametricNDSolve` myself, so I'd be curious to see it.

Answer (score 3):

A solution can be obtained symbolically.

```
q = 1/10; [z_] = 1 - z^2;
```

(For some reason `q` must be rational for `FunctionExpand` to work properly below.)

```
y[z] /. Flatten@DSolve[{f[z] (z y''[z] + y'[z]) == q^2 z y[z]}, y[z], z]
(* C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[-(I/20), I/20, 1, z^2] + 
   C[2] MeijerG[{{}, {1 - I/20, 1 + I/20}}, {{0, 0}, {}}, z^2] *)
sol = FunctionExpand[%, 0 <= z <= 1]
(* C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[-(I/20), I/20, 1, z^2] + 
   (1 - z^2) C[2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - I/20, 1 + I/20, 2, 1 - z^2] *)
```

Now, apply the boundary conditions to `sol`.  (Applying the boundary conditions directly to `DSolve` fails, probably because `MeijerG` is an unfriendly function.

```
sol/. z -> 1
(* {C[1]/(Gamma[1 - I/20] Gamma[1 + I/20]) *)
```

So, `C[1] == 0`.

```
D[sol /. C[1] -> 0, z] /. z -> 1
(* -2*C[2] *)
```

and `C[2] == -1/2`.

```
Plot[sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> -1/2}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {z, y},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: sol is defined for $z>0,z<1$, but you substitute $z=1$ in sol ( @bbgodfrey does not appear when submitting).

Comment: Maple completely  confirms your result (The Maple code on demand through Dropbox.).  @bbgodfrey does not appear when submitting. +1.

Comment: @user64494  I presume you are referring to the limits I used with `FunctionExpand`.  I could just as well have used `0 <= z <= 1`, and perhaps should have.  (I shall make the change.)  Thanks for verifying the solution with Maple and for up-voting the answer.  By the way, my user name does not appear when someone writes a comment here, because, as author of the answer, I receive all comments automatically.  Best wishes.

Comment: Here it is as a PDF file https://www.dropbox.com/s/47fpdfyz3nfffqk/Verification%20with%20Maple.pdf?dl=0